# How to fix "n is not defined" error in this code

Tags: python, math

I know this is an awful piece of code and it is probably unclear what I want to achieve with that. I'm just starting with coding.

Basically I need to find out whether there is (or are) such positive integer `n` that would turn `n*(n+1)(n**2+1)+1` into a perfect square. I know for sure that `3` satisfies the goal, but I can't do anything even with knowing that fact.

It's obvious that there should be a loop that checks the values for `n > 1`, but I can't seem to figure out how to write this down without causing `n is not defined` error. I tried defining `n` through input function and going by hand, but it resulted in this error: `Int ... can't be called.`

```py
# n*(n+1)(n**2+1)+1

import math

n = int(n)
m = n*(n+1)(n**2+1)+1

while n > 1 :
    if math.sqrt(m) == int:
        print(n)
        break
```

Comment: you use `n` in the statement `int(n)` before defining it...

Comment: how to define that n can be any number that is >= 1?

Comment: @GOGA you don't need to. In Python, variables don't have types.

Comment: @gmds okay, so I need to create a list? I'm really confused

Comment: Welcome to Python and SO. So you want to write a loop that tests all positive integers from n>=1 upwards. The obvious thing is a for/while-loop that starts at n=1, tests the condition at that value, prints/breaks if it's satisifed, and counts upward. n starts out uninitialized. **However `n = int(n)` is not doing anything**, and it's not initializing n with any value. It is not declaring "n is some int (whose value we don't yet know)"; I think you're confusing Python with Java/C. In Python we do not separately declare the type of variables; we just initialize them. So: initialize n to 1

Comment: Your second bug after you fix that, is **your while-loop never increments n**. So if you initialize `n=1` before you enter the loop, it will just keep testing the condition for n=1, getting the exact same result, and looping forever without incrementing n. So, what code is missing from the end of your loop to increment n? (Remember, this is why for-loops are simpler than while-loops, they force you both to initialize the loop variable, and to increment (/decrement) it, so you can't forget).

Comment: Your third bug, after you fix the first two, is you never recompute `f(n) = n*(n+1)(n**2+1)+1` inside the loop. You just compute it once for n=1, and store it into the variable m, which never changes, even when n changes. Unnecessary local variables like that are a bad practice. Why not either declare a function `def f(n): ...`? or at least reevaluate the expression inside the loop? Also, a tip is you can avoid computing f(n) or m both outside and inside the loop, by simply changing the loop to `while True:`, then testing any termination conditions inside it.

Comment: Your loop actually is actually going to run forever anyway unless you add some termination condition, since if you start at `n=1` and increment n, the condition `while n>= 1:` will always be `True`. So, `while True` is fine as your loop, and allows you to not need that extra line that initializes `m` outside the loop, which was a bad practice anyway.

Comment: Your fourth bug is again that `math.sqrt(m) == int` does not make any sense in Python, that's not how you test if a number is an integer. Hint: `int(x)` is a function which returns the integer part of x, rounded down.

Comment: @smci you're the best! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would need define n with an initial value.
Then, you can test if m's square root is a whole number and thus m is a perfect square, and you also need to increment n for the next iteration

```
import math
n = 2
while n > 1 :
    m = n*(n+1)(n**2+1)+1
    if math.sqrt(m).is_integer():
        print(n)
        break
    else:
        n+=1
```

Comment: should be `is_integer()`... and to be really sure: `mm = round(math.sqrt(m)); if mm**2 == m: ...`

Comment: this looks like what I need, but there is a mistake in your code I think

Comment: I think it's better to give the OP hints and point out the bugs in their code and guide them towards finding them for themselves, rather than just spoonfeed them the solution.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want:

```
import math
#get a input num
n = int(input('type a num:\n'))
#options that are open:
m = n*(n+1) + (n**2+1)+1 # add
#m = n*(n+1) * (n**2+1)+1 = mul
#m = n*(n+1) / (n**2+1)+1 = div
#m = n*(n+1) - (n**2+1)+1 = sub
#n > 1?
if n > 1 :
    #if the types are the same
    if type(math.sqrt(m)) == type(int):
        print(n)
    #else print the other info about what could be going wrong
    else:
        print(math.sqrt(m))
        print(n)
```

Comment: In general, prefer `isinstance` to checking type equality.

Comment: `math.sqrt(4) = 2.0` . your test with `type(int)` will fail... also you need to update `m` for every `n`...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
import math
n = int(input()) #taking input from user
m = n*(n+1)*(n**2+1)+1 #defining m
o = math.sqrt(m) #taking squareroot 
if int(o) == o: 
   print(str(n) + ' fits the criteria!')
else:
   print(str(n) + ' does not fit the criteria.')
```

Comment: You can call `input` with no arguments too.

Answer (score 0):

`n` is not defined because your code says `n = (int) n` and `n` was never previously defined, so instead try putting a line that say: `n =`, and then a value.